# Fresh Flutter App Error: app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

So, I'm using the command line and VScode. I'm just trying to get Flutter to run so I can try it out again, but I keep running into this error. I used it before a few months ago and now I'm trying to start a new app. Any ideas?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Iverson\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Iverson\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I just reinstalled Java and it started working. Specifically, I made sure Java 8 was working.

Answer (score 0):

You should set minSdkVersion on build.grade by lower number, like this

```
minSdkVersion 21
```